# Android Scaling between two points

Tags: java, android, image, scaling

I'm trying to calculate and scale an image between 2 points. I'm using the e3roid engine for Android. Here is my code

```
 double dx   = as.getRealX() - laser1.getRealX();          
    double dy   = as.getRealY() - laser1.getRealY();
    laser1.scale(2, (float)Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
```

When I test it the image just doesn't show up at all. I made sure that the 2 images that it is scaling between are created first but no avail. Thanks for the help if you help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I just needed to convert the angle to radians.

Comment: How did you convert de angles to radians?